# Not able to search string in files using perl

Tags: perl, shell

I have one small shell script in which I'm searching some of the strings in file and while doing the same in perl I'm not able to get the logic. Please help me.

```
for i in `ls *.txt`
do

    if [[ `cat $i|grep "Records"` && `cat $i|grep "HTTP/Responce authorized"`  && `cat $i|grep "responseData class"` ]]
    then
        echo "Pass" >> temp 
    else
        echo "Fail" >> temp
    fi

done
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'TC_01.txt';
my $value1 = 'totalRecords';
my $value2 = 'responseData';
#my $value3 = '200';

open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>) {
    #print $line;
    #last if $. == 2;
    if (($line =~ /$value1/) && ($line =~ /$value2/)) {
        print "Pass","\n";
        last;
    }
    else {
        print "Fail";
        last;
    }
}
close $info;
```

Comment: Do you have some Perl code you can show?  Note that in Perl, you open a directory with an `opendir` function and iterate through the files, then you `open` each file of interest and iterate through the lines of the file...

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'TC_01.txt';
my $value1 = 'totalRecords';
my $value2 = 'responseData';
#my $value3 = '200';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    #print $line;    
    #last if $. == 2;
    if (($line =~ /$value1/) && ($line =~ /$value2/)){
 print "Pass","\n";
 last; 
 }
     else{
 print "Fail" ;
 last; 
}
}

close $info;

Comment: @user2503377 You should edit your question and add that code instead of posting it in the comments

Comment: whats inside files that u are catting ....put some eg

Answer (score 1):

The following should work as long as you're able to replace string[123] with the text you're actually looking for.

```
my @fileList;

opendir(DIR,"/path/to/dir") || die "error opening directory";
while(readdir(DIR)) {
        if($_ =~ /.*\.txt$/) {push(@fileList,$_)}
}
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $txtFile (@fileList) {

        my ($a,$b,$c) = (0,0,0);
        open(FILE,"<$txtFile");
        while(<FILE>) {
                if($_ =~ /string1/) { $a=1 }
                if($_ =~ /string2/) { $b=1 }
                if($_ =~ /string3/) { $c=1 }
        }
        close(FILE);

        open(OUTFILE,">>temp");
        if($a && $b && $c) {
                print OUTFILE "Pass\n"
        }
        else {
                print OUTFILE "Fail\n"
        }
        close(OUTFILE);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation for the `my $content = do { local $/; <$fh> };` part can be found [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=287647)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# File to write to
open my $temp, ">>", "temp" or die $!;

for my $file (sort glob "*.txt") {
    my $fh;
    open $fh, $file or die $!;
    my $content = do {
        local $/;
        <$fh>;
    };

    if ($content =~ /Records/
            and $content =~ /HTTP\/Responce authorized/
            and $content =~ /responseData class/) {
        print $temp "Pass\n";
    }
    else {
        print $temp "Fail\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working as expected

Comment: Good to know! Make sure to mark as accepted if that solved everything!